# Android networking problems

Tags: android, networking

Hello I have some problems with my Application:
first time: it works and displays my string from server
second time: it doesn`t show my string from server
third time: "has stopped"
What is problems do I have?

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

    private static ArrayList<Products> myProducts;
    ParseJSON parseJSON;

    final String GetMenuUrl = "http://xn--e1aybc.xn--76-6kc1ag2ab9l.xn--p1ai/get_menu.php";
    String City = "Moscow";
    String NameCinema = "Avrora";
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private String response;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        init();
        new RequestTask().execute(GetMenuUrl);
    }

public void init(){
    myProducts = new ArrayList<Products>();
    parseJSON = new ParseJSON();
}


private void setAdapter(ArrayList<String> products){
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listProducts);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();

            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", City));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name_cinema",NameCinema));
            postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            response = hc.execute(postMethod, res);

            parseJSON.parse(response.toString());
            Log.d("response == ", response.toString());
            myProducts = parseJSON.getObjects();

            Log.d("firstProduc == ", myProducts.get(0).getProductName());

            ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i = 0 ; i < myProducts.size(); i++){
                products.add(myProducts.get(i).getProductName());
            }
            setAdapter(products);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exp=" + e);
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MenuActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
```

log says:

```
10-22 16:01:50.132    1604-1604/com.example.kinofood E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.getScrapView(AbsListView.java:6310)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2139)
            at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
            at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 16:01:50.156      476-487/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.example.kinofood/.MenuActivity
```

Comment: What do you mean by first time, second time and third time? How is your activity created? What does the log say when it throws an exception? Where is the exception?

Comment: `NullPointerException` -- find out what's null and make sure it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setAdapter(products);` should be called from the UI `Thread` instead of in `doInBackground()` because you are setting the `Adapter` on the `ListView` and this should be done on the UI `Thread`. Move that call to `onPostExecute()`.

This means you will want to pass `products` to `onPostExecute()` or, probably better, make it a member variable of your task class then you can pass a result to `onPostExecute()` to make sure you received the data before trying to set the `Adapter` instead of returning `null`.

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    //declare it here
    ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // it's a good idea to check if your dialog isn't null and showing
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing() 
            dialog.dismiss();

        // call the method here
        setAdapter(products);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

And, as I said, you might want to check the response in `doInBackground()` or the size of `products` and `return` the response or size to know if you got anything.